# Jquery: Ajax Post not functioning with JinJa Templating

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jinja2

**Objective:** The objective is quite simple. I should be able to Click a button and post information to database.

**Problem:** Clicking button Doesn't post to database.

**Setup:** I am using Flask Framework, Jquery, and Jinja Templating.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
     "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var SCRIPT_ROOT = "";   
    $('#cart').live('click', function(){
    var asin = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[3];
            $.ajax({
                url: SCRIPT_ROOT + '/api' + '/mattel' + '/' + asin,
                datatype: 'json',
                error: function() {
                    alert("No Dice!");
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data.product, data.asin);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: SCRIPT_ROOT + '/api/shopping',
                        data: JSON.stringify({"asin":data.asin, "user":"lwgray@gmail.com", "store":data.store, "product":data.product}),
                        error: function() {
                            alert("No Dice, Again!");
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data.product);
                            },
                        dataType: 'json'
                    });
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

**Question:**  My question you'll is where am I going wrong? It used to work before.

Comment: You should post your python function code which handles your ajax `POST` method.

Comment: `.live()` was deprecated since jQuery 1.7, removed in 1.9. You're using 1.11. http://api.jquery.com/live/ You should use `.on()` instead. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

This probably doesn't work because you're using `.live()` and jQuery 1.11. `.live()` was replaced by `.on()` in jQuery 1.9.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
     "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var SCRIPT_ROOT = "";   
    $('#cart').on('click', function(){
    var asin = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[3];
            $.ajax({
                url: SCRIPT_ROOT + '/api' + '/mattel' + '/' + asin,
                datatype: 'json',
                error: function() {
                    alert("No Dice!");
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data.product, data.asin);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: SCRIPT_ROOT + '/api/shopping',
                        data: JSON.stringify({"asin":data.asin, "user":"lwgray@gmail.com", "store":data.store, "product":data.product}),
                        error: function() {
                            alert("No Dice, Again!");
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data.product);
                            },
                        dataType: 'json'
                    });
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```